# PHP Moving an array into different text files?

Tags: php

I've been given a list of data and I need to split it and move it into different text files. I've tried a few things so far but cant seem to get it to work.

```
<?php

/*
*order the file based on surname (col 2)
*create two new text files - class A and B
*split the source text into two equal lists
*format them: ID, firstname, lastname. all words must be first letter caps
*move each list to a new file.
*close files
*/

//This function converts every attribute/variable passed to it into a sentence case
function Uppercase($convert) {
    return ucwords($convert);
}

//This function compares two items to see which one is higher
//src: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
function cmp($a, $b) {
$compResult = strcmp($a[1], $b[1]);

if ($compResult == 0) {
    return strcmp($a[2], $b[2]);
}else {
    return $compResult;
}
}

//This function gets rid of the whitespace that is not needed
function cut($c) {
    return trim($c, " \n\r\0");
}

//open file
$myfile = fopen("students.csv", "r");

echo "A";

//initialise the array, giving them 'headers'
$array = array();

echo "B";

//sort through the data, moving it to a multidimentional array and setting the   first letter in each item to uppercase
$i=0;

while(!feof($myfile)){
$line = fgets($myfile);

$pieces = explode(",", $line);
$array[$i][0] = $pieces[0];
$array[$i][1] = cut(Uppercase($pieces[2]));
$array[$i][2] = cut(Uppercase($pieces[1]));

$i++;
}   

echo "C";

//sort the file by the second item in the array
usort($array, "cmp");
echo array_shift($array)."<br>";

echo "D";

//create class files
$fileA = fopen("Class 1.txt", "w");
$fileB = fopen("Class 2.txt", "w");

echo "E";

//get size of array
$arraylength = count($array);

//half the array length(
$half = ceil($arraylength /= 2);
//echo $half;

//echo $arraylength."</br>";
echo "F";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</br>";

//move the first class into a text file
$k = 0;

foreach ($array as $key){
    echo $key[0];

     if ($k < $half) {
        $current = file_get_contents($fileA);
        $current .= $key;
    }
}

 echo "G";

fclose($fileA);
fclose($fileB);
fclose($myfile);

echo "H";
```

When this runs, I get the following line recurring for each item in the array

> Warning:  file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPLabs\EE1600Assignment.php on line 93

The document itself has 25 items that look like this:

```
123, billy, bobs
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` expects a file path, but you are providing a file handler. You probably want instead `fgets($fileA)`.

Alternatively, if you want to read the complete file (it's not entirely clear from your code), you can use `fread($fileA)`.

Comment: For FileA and FileB, all I want to do is write the data to it from the array. I guess thats the first answer you suggested

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), file_get_contents requires a path to the file you want to open (as per the error message you're getting - `file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path`).

You're passing in `$fileA` - which you created earlier using an fopen call

`fopen("Class 1.txt", "w");`